# Function is an object of class in python?

Tags: python, function

I read that a function is an object of a class in python.To further understand, i did below:

```
>>> a=10
>>> a.__class__
<type 'int'>
>>> int.__class__
<type 'type'>
>>>
>>>
>>> def T1():
...     print 'test'
...
>>> T1.__class__
<type 'function'>
>>> function.__class__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

Q:why does the interpreter throw an error in the second case and not in the first case? I was expecting it to return `<type 'type'>`.Please correct my understanding.

Comment: **Everything is an object** in Python.

Comment: In your second case, `function` is not a defined _name_, which is why it throws an exception. What you wanted to do was `function = T1.__class__; function.__class__` or `T1.__class__.__class_`.

Comment: A better way to say it is "a function is an _instance_ of a class in python".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function type, but there is no built-in name for it. You can find another reference there under the `types` module:

```
>>> import types
>>> def T1():
...     pass
...     
>>> T1.__class__ is types.FunctionType
True
>>> print(repr(types.FunctionType))
<class 'function'>
```

So, the only difference here is that `function` is not a built-in name, unlike names such as `int`. If you want that name in your namespace for some reason, you can just bind it:

```
>>> function = type(lambda: 0)
>>> function
<class 'function'>
```

Comment: why does T1.__class__.__class__   does not throw error?Pardon my ignorance

Comment: @fsociety Because the class of `T1` *also* has a class, which is `type`. *Everything in Python is an object*.

Comment: I am not sure why 'isinstance(T1.__class__, types.FunctionType)' is 'False'?

Comment: @TomJ `T1.__class__ is types.FunctionType`, not an instance.  `T1` itself is a function instance, so `isinstance(T1, types.FunctionType)`

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. Say you create your own metaclass (class of a class), and a subclass of your metaclass (which is itself just a class):

```
>>> class MyMeta(type): # <-- a custom metaclass, similar to function
        pass

>>> print(MyMeta.__name__)
MyMeta
>>> print(__class__)
<class 'type'>

>>> class MyClass(metaclass = MyMeta):
        pass
>>> print(MyClass.__class__)
<class 'MyMeta'>
```

Now, we will delete the identifier `MyMeta`:

```
>>> del MyMeta
```

Can you still get to the metaclass object that was represented by `MyMeta` although `MyMeta` has been deleted? Sure:

```
>>> print(MyClass.__class__)
<class 'MyMeta'>
```

So there is still a reference to the metaclass object in the `MyClass` dict.

However, the ***name*** `MyMeta` is now invalid, since it was deleted:

```
>>> class MyClassTwo(metaclass = MyMeta):
        pass
NameError!!
>>> print(MyMeta.__name__)
NameError!!
>>> print(MyMeta)
NameError!!
```

IMPORTANT: The metaclass ***name*** has been deleted, not the metaclass object itself.

Therefore you can still access the metaclass ***object*** this way:

```
>>> class MyClassTwo(metaclass = MyClass.__class__):
        pass
```

So it is with the `function` name (which is itself kind of like a built-in metaclass; i.e., it is the class, or type, of function objects)- by default, the ***name*** `function` doesn't exist in an interactive Python session. But the ***object*** does still exist. You can access it this way:

```
>>> def f(): pass
>>> f.__class__.__class__
<class 'type'>
```

And if you like, you can even go ahead and assign the name `function` to the function `<class 'type'>` object (although there's not much reason to do that):

```
>>> function  = f.__class__
>>> print(function)
<class 'function'>
>>> print(function.__class__)
<class 'type'>
```